# Certain escape characters can be copied while editing, but not after

Tags: feature-request, edits, visibility, escape-character

(First off, this has **nothing** to do with backslashes) While editing [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245365/111322) to a Code Golf challenge, I noticed that a certain escape character behaved in an odd way.

The specific character is `\x1b`. When I'm editing a post, and include that character in the code (you can see it in the [online code](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDSTra2MLayNrA2sLc2tDCOLe6Fixiam1kZJBbbVCrpKOhFKGkV5RakJpYomFuoamtxKWkCeMbGmtq1v7/DwA), right after `print!("`), I can go down to the edit preview, copy the code, paste it, and the character will be there. However, when I save the edits, and copy the code from the edited post, the character doesn't appear when I paste it.

Could we make sure that certain escape characters make it into the post's code after an edit?

Comment: What is \x1b? Unicode code point [U+001B](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=27&number=128)? [ASCII 27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart) (ESC)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: What is special about this one? For [colours in a terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)? [OSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Read my linked answer (and the question it answers): it's for colors in a terminal.